# Can I style an element using its grandparent's properties, but then set its parent to be different?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style the background colour of an element using the background colour belonging to its grandparent, but then set its parent to have a different colour. Is this possible?

I thought that having its parent set to `inherit` and then the element set to `inherit` to 'cascade' it down would work, and that then I would be free to change the background colour of the parent, but this hasn't worked.

Below is a stripped-down version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```css
div {
  background-color: #e00;
}
span.foo {
  background-color: inherit;
}
span.bar {
  background-color: inherit;
}
span.foo {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="foo">
    Hello
    <span class="bar">
      World
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can't do it like that. You'll have to set the "bar" span background explicitly. One simple approach would be to just introduce another class or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want using CSS, but your question also demonstrates that you have an incorrect idea about how CSS works, so its important to explain why you can't do what you want:

CSS is **not** a programming language - it does not have a serial model of operations - do this, then do that, like programing languages do.

CSS is a description language - it allows you to describe the properties of objects without a time function. That is - when you say "inherit" in CSS, it does not mean "copy the value and maintain your own copy", it means "this value is exactly like the parent, and it will always be exactly like the patent, even if the parent changes" - because it is not an operation, it's a description of how things are.

Another example, is when you write something like:

```
p { color: green; }
p { color: red; }
```

It doesn't mean "draw the text using green color then using red color" - it means "the designer thought that he wants the text green, then decided that red is better - so always draw the text using red".

If you really want to do something like copying the value of another element and then changing the source element, you'd need to use a programming language - though I think it's best if you try to think of a way to get the style that you need by using only CSS's descriptive properties.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for replying and showing me my ignorance. But, surely the fact that the later declaration holds whereas the first one does not means that the order in which things are done has some value, no?

Comment: The order itself of text written in a linear fashion only has value in the sense that later text can overwrite previous text while the reverse is not true. For the purpose of CSS, you can think of the process of rendering CSS as a "compile" stage where the CSS text is parsed line by line to create the complete description followed by a rendering stage where the resulting description is applied to the page.

Comment: Another feature of the order of CSS rules, is that if one rule is overriding another, then a CSS debug tool (such that is common to find in a browser "developer tools" feature) allows you to disable some rules and see what would have happened if they were not written.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using jquery on page load i.e:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

var divColor = $("div").css("background-color");
$(".bar").css("background-color", divColor);

});

</scipt>
```

Hope this helps.